# Require some access token

Tags: facebook, permissions, require, access-token, facebook-access-token

I ask for `read_stream` permission in my app. But the users can ***ignore*** that request. How can I check if the user gave me the permission?

I want that permission to be **required** in order to use the app.

---

I'm using PHP SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this:

```
$facebook->api('USER_ID/permissions','GET');
```

You'll get the permissions the user has granted to your app

You can find more info here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/handling-revoked-permissions/